# Getting value twice in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function

I have a `SQL` like this;

```
SELECT  B.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2 AS 'TEKLIF',B.MUS_K_ISIM,
dbo.fngcodeme(B.HESAP_NO, B.DOVIZ_KOD, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2,'11/03/2011', '11/03/2011'),
(CASE WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 21 THEN 'EUR' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 2 THEN 'USD' WHEN B.DOVIZ_KOD = 1 THEN 'TL' END) AS 'KUR',
D.AVUKAT, 
(CASE WHEN D.HESAP IN (SELECT T_HESAP_NO FROM TAKIP) THEN 
(SELECT ICRA_TAR FROM TAKIP WHERE T_HESAP_NO = D.HESAP)
ELSE ' ' END) AS 'ICRA TARİHİ', 
(CASE WHEN D.HESAP IN (SELECT T_HESAP_NO FROM TAKIP) THEN 
(SELECT HACIZ_TAR FROM TAKIP WHERE T_HESAP_NO = D.HESAP)
ELSE '' END) AS 'HACİZ TARİHİ'
FROM YAZ..MARDATA.S_TEKLIF B, AVUKAT D
WHERE B.HESAP_NO = D.HESAP
AND ISNULL(dbo.fngcodeme(B.HESAP_NO, B.DOVIZ_KOD, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2,'11/03/2011', '11/03/2011'),0) > 0
GROUP BY B.HESAP_NO, B.TEKLIF_NO1 + '/' + B.TEKLIF_NO2,B.DOVIZ_KOD ,B.MUS_K_ISIM, D.AVUKAT, D.HESAP
```

Here is my tables;

```
S_TEKLIF (B)    AVUKAT      TAKIP

HESAP_NO (PK)   HESAP(PK)   T_HESAP_NO (PK)
TEKLIF_NO1      MUS_K_ISIM  ICRA_TAR
TEKLIF_NO2      AVUKAT      HACIZ_TAR
MUS_K_ISIM              
DOVIZ_KOD
```

And here is mine `dbo.fngcodeme` Function;

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fngcodeme]
(
    @HESAP INT, @DOV INT, @TEKLIF VARCHAR(10), @BAS  VARCHAR(10), @BIT  VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS FLOAT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result FLOAT

SET @Result = (SELECT SUM(TUTAR)
    FROM YAZ..MARDATA.M_GHAREKET
    WHERE TEMEL_HESAP = @HESAP
    AND DOVIZ_KOD = @DOV
    AND REF_KOD = 'GC'
    AND BACAK_GRUP = 'PERT'
    AND ISL_KOD = 1
    AND ACIKLAMA LIKE '%' + @TEKLIF + '%'
    AND ISL_TAR >= CONVERT(DATETIME, + '' + @BAS + '',103)
    AND ISL_TAR <= CONVERT(DATETIME, + '' + @BIT + '',103)
    )

RETURN @Result

END
```

My top `SQL` is working perfect but gettin two value with the same data.

[image]

Where the error i could be doing?

**Best Regards,**

**Soner**

Comment: It is not same data - TEKLIF is different (you have multiple corresponding records in B table).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the same, the `TEKLIF` column differs. You group on that column, hence you will get two results of they differ.

Comment: you have eyes like eagle :) Thanks..!